# Why Javafx GUI for UDP Server stops working

Tags: java, maven, javafx, crash, udp

I have created a UDP server that is always listening to get data from clients. The server alone- without GUI- works fine and does all required. I made a simple GUI for it using javafx, so that when the user presses on a button, the server starts working and keeps track of received packets. But when I click on the start button GUI stops working. what am I doing wrong?

The GUI

```
@FXML
//buttons
public Button start_btn;

//text boxes to enter values
public TextField sentPackets;


@FXML
private void start_btnClicked() throws IOException, InterruptedException, SQLException {

    Server obj = new Server();
    obj.main(null);
}
```

Server

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {

    System.out.println("-------------------Server Listening-------------------");

    String line;

    // Step 1 : Create a socket to listen at port 1234
    DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(1234);
    byte[] receive = new byte[65535];

    DatagramPacket DpReceive = null;

    while (true) {

        // Step 2 : create a DatgramPacket to receive the data.
        DpReceive = new DatagramPacket(receive, receive.length);

        // Step 3 : revieve the data in byte buffer.
        ds.receive(DpReceive);

        System.out.println("Client:-" + data(receive));

        line = data(receive).toString();

        String str = line;
        String[] arrOfStr = str.split("@", 100);


        db obj = new db();
        obj.DB(arrOfStr);


        // Clear the buffer after every message.
        receive = new byte[65535];
    }

}
// A utility method to convert the byte array
// data into a string representation.
public static StringBuilder data(byte[] a)
{
    if (a == null)
        return null;
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (a[i] != 0)
    {
        ret.append((char) a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You're running an infinite loop on the FX Application Thread, preventing the FX Application Thread from doing its normal work (drawing the UI, processing user events, etc.). It's not really clear what you're doing here anyway; the `main(...)` method is the entry point for an application; if you're calling it in code you're almost certainly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main method sits in the while (true) loop, so the start_btnClicked method  never returns.

Instead of calling main, why not make your Server class implement Runnable. Then, when the button is clicked you can instantiate a Server and start it, which will return allow the start method to return

Comment: Thank you so very much, fixed it using your solution all the way. Thank you